# One to many relationship , How can I add data to a one to many relationship field?

Tags: django, one-to-many

How can I add data to a one to many relationship field?

The model structures are given below

I am having two models, an Admin model and other one is the App model.

An app may have multiple admins (App 1- u1 , u2... as app admins)

```
class Admin(models.Model):
email = models.EmailField()


class App(models.Model):

platform = models.IntegerField()  # 1-iOS, 2-ANDROID
bundle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
admin = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Tried of saving a list of admins to  the app but, it is not working as expected with this model structure.

Comment: Have you read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) ?

Comment: It works the other way around. If you want to sae a list of `Admin`s to an `App`, the `Admin` has a foreign key to the `App`, not the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case an admin can have only one APP, but an app can be owned by multiple admins. So each admin needs to have a reference to the app he/she owns.

You nee to add a foreign key to the admin model, referencing the app he/she owns.

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Then obviously you need to remove the foreign key reference of admin from your app model:

```
class App(models.Model):
    platform = models.IntegerField()  # 1-iOS, 2-ANDROID
    bundle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class Admin(models.Model):
 email = models.EmailField()
 app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class App(models.Model):
 platform = models.IntegerField()  # 1-iOS, 2-ANDROID
 bundle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now 1 App can have multiple Admins

One more thing that you can do is:

```
Admin...
...
 app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='admins')

...


So now you can query AppObject.admins.all() for admin of that AppObject
```

Comment: Thankyou, modified the model structure and  it is working now